# How can I tell if a project is done with a PHP framework?

Tags: php, laravel, zend-framework

I am working on a project (already started), but I do not know if it is done with framework since there are files in many different folders, but I do not see any syntax referring to some framework that I know of.

I hope someone can help me...

Comment: Try to look and the folder structure and match it with the different frameworks structure. Also, you can look for comments in the code for getting more insights.

Comment: Have you got a `composer.json` file? Most recent framework use that to load dependencies so that's a good way to know what's used...

Answer (score 7):

Well it would depend on the Folder Hierarchies and the code.

If the views folder has the term "blade" on it, it's definitely laravel.
If the the code of the library has the term "CI Controller" somewhere in the libraries its definitely CodeIgniter.
If the code has a lot of "wp-" string in its code, its definitely Wordpress.

TIP: Put the whole folder in Sublime, search the folder (right click the folder and choose "Find in folder...") and search for terms that are generally reserved words for mostly used frameworks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Comment: upvoted for the answer but it isnt sufficient I think

Answer (score 3):

There are different methods to identify the PHP framework used by a web application. But one of the easiest way I would like to share it with you to use this extension in your browser called [Wappalyzer](https://www.wappalyzer.com/).

Wappalyzer is a cross-platform utility that uncovers the technologies used on websites. It detects content management systems, e-commerce platforms, web frameworks, server software, analytics tools and many more.

There are a few other tools out there that analyze what a website is using.

[BuiltWith](https://builtwith.com/) - Stand alone site, also available as a plugin

[W3Techs](https://w3techs.com/sites) - Stand alone site, also available as a plugin

Answer (score 1):

Auto-generated comments may also help. In my case, I can tell from the comments in `index.php` that it's written in `CodeIgniter`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a copy of the project hosted somewhere you can use https://builtwith.com